# Screen recording / Screen capture programme for Mac that can record at lower resolutions to output small file sizes?

Tags: screen-recording

I often need to make screen capture videos to demonstrate a software feature / workflow to people.

Im on OSX 10.13 and currently i use the inbuilt Quicktime screen capture feature, which works fine, but outputs huge files. Its not uncommon for a 5 minute video to be >500mb.

In order to be able to share these i then have to put the videos into handbrake to compress them, which although works takes allot of time.

Are there any screen capture programmes for OSX that have inbuilt compression so i can record natively to say 720p 15fps, so that the file sizes will stay small ?

Answer (score 1):

[Screenium](https://www.syniumsoftware.com/screenium) is exactly what you are looking for, although it's a bit pricey.

Answer (score 1):

[OBS](https://obsproject.com/) is very good and it has a OS X version.

Its free & open source.

A 2 hour video is about 1.7 GB big, with decent quality.

With a little bit less decent quality and not much to capture (A video of writing code for example) 1 hour is about 25 MB big...